# Jackson Serialization of Interfaces

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson

I’m trying to use Jackson-datatype-xml to serialize java objects to XML. When doing so, I have an interface such as:

```
interface SpecificationType {...}

class FreeText implements SpecificationType {...}

class Selection implements SpecificationType {...}
```

Because of this interface, I have another class that uses it as a field:

```
class Question {

    private final SpecificationType specificationType;

    ....

}
```

The problem is that when I serialize this to XML the tag will be `SpecificationType` when I want it to reflect the concrete class `FreeText` (for example). Is there a way to do this with Jackson?

Eg.

I get:

```
<SpecificationType>...</SpecificationType>
```

I want:

```
<FreeText>...</FreeText>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to achieve that is, I think, by enabling polymorphic typing. So you can try adding `@JsonProperty` on property in question, with inclusion type of `As.WRAPPER_OBJECT`.
This will then use "type id" as element which is what you want here. But one thing I am not 100% sure without trying it whether there will be an extra element in there; it should be easy enough to try it out and see what the result looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! OP is a co-op I'm working with; we'll take a look at this tomorrow.

Comment: @mattklamp great! Thank you for verifying.